# Alter table with select insert statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table in MySQL database which get its data from another table.

```
  create table test as select id,name,value from test2
```

Now i want to insert another column data from same test2 table such as country into test.
Can i alter or update test table.Any suggestions will really help me.I tried like this:

```
alter table test add (select country from test2)
```

thanks

Comment: Why not just drop it and recreate with new columns.

Comment: would  "create table test as select id,name,value,'' as country from test2"  work?